# Changing html of <p> without changing <span>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a span inside a paragraph and want to be able to change the paragraph text and the span text from button clicks. Right now when I call the function the paragraph is updated but the span disappears.

```html
<p id = "a">Some text to change <span id = "b" onmouseenter="test()">click!</span></p>
```

```js
function test() {
   $("#a").html("New text here");
   $("#b").html("click again!");
}
```

Comment: I hardly ever use jquery but I guess that replacing `.html()` by `.text()` may work.

Comment: @AlexSp3 That would not be a good guess in this situation

Comment: @charlietfl why do you say that?

Comment: @AlexSp3 Setting text() or innerText will wipe out any existing html content also

Comment: @charlietfl ahh ok, good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the HTML of the parent `p`, it will remove everything inside it. However, you can restructure your html to have two `span`s inside the `p` and update the text of those.

Here's an example with `#c` as the first span and `#b` as the second:

```js
function test() {
   $("#c").text("New text here ");
   $("#b").text("click again!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id = "a"><span id = "c">Some text to change </span><span id = "b" onmouseenter="test()">click!</span></p>
```